# Syntax-error in ElephantSQL at or near GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone help me solve this problem with elephantsql?

```
SELECT people.name 
FROM people
INNER JOIN partof ON partof.person_id = people.person_id
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.team_id = partof.team_id
INNER JOIN winners ON winners.team_id = teams.team_id
HAVING COUNT (winners.team_id) >= 1
GROUP BY people.name;
```

Why does This give a syntax error?

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 7: GROUP BY people.name;
```

I've tried adding a comma after the HAVING-statement but no luck.
I'm still very new to SQL, hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Having comes after group by

Comment: the `HAVING` clause usually must be last in most SQLs

Comment: That HAVING clause makes no difference at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah! Of course :D Thank you @Andrew

Comment: @jarlh I'm trying to make my database show the names of all teammembers (in the Rainbow SX: Siege - pro league) from the teams which have at least 1 won tournament.

Comment: @CasaRol - jarlh's point above is correct, that having clause will do nothing, the inner join already is ensuring that the team is in the winners table at least once, so you probably have something else wrong here which is semantically incorrect, opposed to syntax.

Comment: @Andrew Doesn't the HAVING prevent the databsse from returning the same team twice if they've won more than one tournament or should I use DISTINCT in the SELECT call intead?

Comment: No need for GROUP BY and HAVING. Simply do SELECT DISTINCT.